# Spring - Extending classes with hibernate and spring security

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-security

I want to have a user class, a student class and a teacher class. With the student and teacher class extending user. What is the best way to do this with Hibernate and spring security. At the moment, I have user with the expected fields and:

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="user_roles",
           joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
           inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
           private Role role;
```

to help with spring security. Everything works fine with just using users, but now I am trying to extend the user class and I don't really know how to start. How does hibernate deal with the extended classes? Can I still have students and teachers in a big user repository? How does spring security work with this as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have Spring Security's UserDetailsService implementation that would work for your User, Teacher, Student instances.

To achieve this, you could use Hibernate inheritance support and a polymorthic query to obtain user info.

Hibernate has several strategies to represent inheritance (*Mapped Superclass*, *Single Table*, *Joined Table*, *Table per Class*): http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance

*Mapped Superclass* is not suitable as it does not support polymorphic queries. The others 3 do.

Inside your UserDetailsService implementation you could do something like

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = (User) getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback() {
        public Object doInHibernate(Session session)
                throws HibernateException, SQLException {
            Query query = session.createQuery("select u from User u where login = ?");
            query.setParameter(0, username);
            return query.uniqueResult();
        }
    });
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Unauthorized");
    }

    // ... usual password check follows...

    // ... create UserDetails as usual
}
```